# Google maps aerial view

Tags: google-maps, images

Is it possiblet to access google maps aerial view? I know that pictures and functionality are still there somewhere.

When accessing from desktop via browser google maps now offer two views: map and satellite. When in satellite mode if zoomed close enough you get 3D reconstructed view of the buildings and features when its available. Otherwise you just get tilted 2D satellite images. This is great for some purposes. But occasionally I want to see actual aerial photos. It used to be possible but I cannot do this from maps.gooogle.com anymore...

However I found out that if google maps are embedded in some other website the functionality is still there. One working example is UK property website www.rightmove.co.uk. If one opens a property listing and switches to map mode, then it is possible to browse to literally any part of the map and view aerial photos.

On Embedded map:
[image]

On maps.google.com:
[image]

Comment: did you try switching between 2D and 3D mode? also, there is https://earth.google.com/web/ which could satisfy you

Comment: @user0 switching between 2D and 3D does not resolve the problem.